# Prevent duplicate entry in php

Tags: php

I want to prevent duplicate entry. It will work when I enter same name that is already exist but if I change it in to small letter it will not work. For example Already exist data is: Developer.If I enter Developer it give message already exist but I enter developer it will insert into database.

My code is as follow:

```
  function insert_skills()
  {
      extract($_POST);
      $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $Qry = mysql_query("select `role_id` from `tbl_job_role` where`industry_id`='$industry_id' AND `funarea_id`='$funarea_id' AND `role_name`='$job_role'") or die(mysql_error());
      if(mysql_num_rows($Qry)>0)
      {
           echo "Already Exist!";
      }
      else
      {
              mysql_query("insert into `tbl_job_role`(`industry_id`,`funarea_id`,`role_name`,`created_by`,`created_on`) values('$industry_id','$funarea_id','$job_role','$user_id',NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
              setcookie("msg","Successfully Inserted.",time()+5);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Developer and developer are different.Try to use case sensitive code

Answer (score 1):

Hi use LOWER function for that

```
LOWER(`Value`) = LOWER("value")
```

Something like this

```
"select `role_id` from `tbl_job_role` where`industry_id`='$industry_id' AND `funarea_id`='$funarea_id' AND LOWER(`role_name`) = LOWER('$job_role')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you use `LIKE`

```
$Qry = mysql_query("select `role_id` from `tbl_job_role`
                    where`industry_id`='$industry_id' 
                       AND `funarea_id`='$funarea_id' 
                       AND `role_name` LIKE '$job_role'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: LIKE use case-sensitive matching. Not advisable in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Use `iLIKE` in your query. It will look like

```
$Qry = mysql_query("select `role_id` from `tbl_job_role` where`industry_id`='$industry_id' AND `funarea_id`='$funarea_id' AND `role_name` iLIKE '$job_role'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem.